# emacs multiple-cursors insert letters (numbers) issue

Tags: insert, multiple-cursors

I've created an ascii video at https://asciinema.org/a/63b67gx2hm5pasdvjkhiyq4ud to demo my emacs issue with multiple-cursors. I created 4 lines of text and created 4 cursors (see 00:36). Then I use `C-a` moved the cursors to the beginning of the lines. After that, I use `mc/insert-letters` to insert letters (see 00:46).  Note that at this time the status line shows `mc:4` means I have 4 cursors.  After I inserted the letters, the status line shows `mc:3` (see 00:49) and the mini buffer is still activated with the command `mc/insert-letters` selected by default. If I press Enter again, the letters `a, b, c` only installed in line 2, 3, 4 and the status line shows `mc:4` again. At the end of the video, I tried the command `mc/insert-numbers` and it shows similar behavior. It seems this behavior is not correct. Could anyone help to confirm please? If it's an issue, how to fix it?